# Move nltk_data folder off C: drive

Tags: python, nltk

I recently have been using Python, utilizing the NLTK library. NLTK has to download packages after the install which total to about 5gb. Since my C: drive is not very large is it possible to move it to another drive?
[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXw7P.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nltk` will automatically look for the `nltk_data` folder in a list of standard locations. On Windows systems, these include the following:

```
    r"C:\nltk_data", r"D:\nltk_data, r"E:\nltk_data"
```

In other words, you can simply place it at the top level in your `D:` or `E:` drive and it [will be found](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/data.html) without further ado.

I'm pretty sure the above covers your use case, but for completeness:

Other standard locations include `nltk_data` and `lib\nltk_data` in the folder containing your Python distribution, and `nltk_data` in your `Application Data` folder (environment variable `%APPDATA%`).

If none of the above suit your purposes, you can specify additional (non-standard) locations to search through the environment variable `NLTK_DATA` (a `;`-separated list of folders on Windows; or `:`-separated on Unix systems), or by modifying the list `nltk.data.path` in your running Python program.

Windows example:

```
set NLTK_DATA=D:\some\path\to\nltk_data;E:\some\other\path
```

Unix example (bash etc.):

```
export NLTK_DATA="$HOME/some/path/nltk_data:$HOME/library/nltk_data"
```

Or from inside Python:

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path.append(r"D:\some\path\to\nltk_data")
```